# Splice Array is rest a null value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using this code to remove a item from Array in React Native:

```
var array = [...this.state.gallery];
if (index !== -1) {
   array.splice(index, 1);
   this.setState({gallery: array,
   photosHaveNow: this.state.photosHaveNow - 1});
}
```

But, when item is removed, that array is write in your place:

```
{"empty": true, "key": "blank-2"}
```

Final example:

```
["http://parquedasfeiras.online/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/WhatsApp-Image-2019-11-30-at-00.38.33.jpeg", "http://parquedasfeiras.online/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/WhatsApp-Image-2019-11-30-at-00.38.33-1.jpeg", "http://parquedasfeiras.online/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/WhatsApp-Image-2019-11-30-at-00.38.33-2.jpeg", "http://parquedasfeiras.online/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/WhatsApp-Image-2019-11-30-at-00.38.33-3.jpeg", "http://parquedasfeiras.online/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/WhatsApp-Image-2019-11-30-at-00.38.34.jpeg", "http://parquedasfeiras.online/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/WhatsApp-Image-2019-11-30-at-00.38.34-1.jpeg", "http://parquedasfeiras.online/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/WhatsApp-Image-2019-11-30-at-00.38.34-4.jpeg", {"empty": true, "key": "blank-2"}, {"empty": true, "key": "blank-2"}, {"empty": true, "key": "blank-2"}, {"empty": true, "key": "blank-2"}, {"empty": true, "key": "blank-2"}]
```

When an item is removed through the splice, "{" empty ": true," key ":" blank-2 "}" is put in place, I wish nothing was put in place.

Comment: The question is not clear. Do u want to replace the removed item by that object? or anything else. please edit the question clearly. Provide the data to be processed.

Comment: Hi, sorry When an item is removed through the splice, "{" empty ": true," key ":" blank-2 "}" is put in place, I wish nothing was put in place.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found a solution. I don't know if it sounds good.

```
    var array = [...this.state.gallery];

    if (index !== -1) {
        array.splice(index, 1);
    }

    var finalArray = [];

    array.forEach(element => {
        if(typeof element !== 'object')
        {
            finalArray = finalArray.concat(element)
        }
    })

    this.setState({
        gallery: finalArray,
        photosHaveNow: this.state.photosHaveNow - 1
    })
```

Comment: ok this is pretty wrong. you're pushing that object in your array somewhere in your code. so find and fix that piece of code. probably in your "deleteItem" function.